# What does the `maxReplicas` property mean in the pipeline yaml in Azure in context of the k8s deployment?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, yaml, pipeline, replication

What does the `maxReplicas` property mean in the pipeline yaml in Azure in context of the k8s deployment?

E.g. in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-scale?tabs=azure-cli) documentation the `maxReplicas: 10` is mentioned. But there is no explanation about what it means. At least I was not able to find one. Would be grateful if someone will help me to find the documentation on that.

I have two assumptions.

First, it means that we need to duplicate pods. I.e. with the `maxReplicas: 10` we may have up to 10 clusters with identical pods.

Second assumption, the `maxReplicas: 10` means that in a k8s cluster we can have no more than 10 pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/

Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-scale?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: **define max replica count**

Comment: So, it means the maximum number of pods to which a cluster can scale out. Is it correct?

Comment: Exactly! Obviously related to a specific Deployment.